# 13" MacBook Pro gets daily kernel panics

Tags: mac, osx-lion, kernel, kernel-panic

My software is OS X Lion 10.7.4 and I've reinstalled it 4 or 5 times to try to solve the kernel panic problems. It's better now, but still unstable. It's a Core i7 2.8 GHz (dual core) with 8 GB RAM and a Toshiba 750 GB hard drive.

```
Fri Jun 15 03:23:24 2012
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80002c473a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80002665f4, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000100f65b7c, CR3: 0x0000000008a19001, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000002, RBX: 0x0000000000000001, RCX: 0xffffff80008de0e0, RDX: 0xffffff80008960a0
RSP: 0xffffff80f063bc70, RBP: 0xffffff80f063bc70, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0xffff008015cacdc0
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x0000000000000002, R10: 0x0000000000000020, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff8015cb8aa2, R13: 0x0000000000000008, R14: 0xffff008015cacdc0, R15: 0xffff008015cacdc0
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff80002665f4, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0x0000000100f65b7c, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80f063b920 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff80f063b9a0 : 0xffffff80002c473a 
0xffffff80f063bb50 : 0xffffff80002da0cd 
0xffffff80f063bb70 : 0xffffff80002665f4 
0xffffff80f063bc70 : 0xffffff800027f598 
0xffffff80f063bca0 : 0xffffff8000283002 
0xffffff80f063bcd0 : 0xffffff8000571179 
0xffffff80f063bce0 : 0xffffff80002ff971 
0xffffff80f063bd30 : 0xffffff80002ff59e 
0xffffff80f063bd70 : 0xffffff8000300f0e 
0xffffff80f063bde0 : 0xffffff800030e50a 
0xffffff80f063be30 : 0xffffff80002fe9c6 
0xffffff80f063be50 : 0xffffff8000550314 
0xffffff80f063bed0 : 0xffffff800055c387 
0xffffff80f063bf50 : 0xffffff80005cd61b 
0xffffff80f063bfb0 : 0xffffff80002daa13 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
11E53

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: A8ED611D-FB0F-3729-8392-E7A32C5E7D74
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 8397388265813
last loaded kext at 33899841375: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 (addr 0xffffff7f81814000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 244519068858: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   4.4.5 (addr 0xffffff7f80a91000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.26
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.1.8
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.42
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.5f11
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.1.9
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.5f11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.1.2b2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   530.4.20
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 193.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   193.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc17
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.0f3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.0.16
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.0d17
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.5f11
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.5f11
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 227.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.5
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.6
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fri Jun 15 01:03:06 2012
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80002c473a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80002eaac9, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff8117fb3d20, CR3: 0x000000002116202d, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff8011e1a648, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000025000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff812c0db0f0, RBP: 0xffffff812c0db100, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0x0000ff0000000000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x000000000000000b, R10: 0x000000002c0d17b6, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff801deefc18, R14: 0x000000000000000b, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff80002eaac9, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0xffffff8117fb3d20, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff812c0dada0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff812c0dae20 : 0xffffff80002c473a 
0xffffff812c0dafd0 : 0xffffff80002da0cd 
0xffffff812c0daff0 : 0xffffff80002eaac9 
0xffffff812c0db100 : 0xffffff80002ec67b 
0xffffff812c0db150 : 0xffffff80002ffa46 
0xffffff812c0db1a0 : 0xffffff80002ff59e 
0xffffff812c0db1e0 : 0xffffff80002ffbde 
0xffffff812c0db210 : 0xffffff80002ffc3c 
0xffffff812c0db230 : 0xffffff8000500f79 
0xffffff812c0db390 : 0xffffff800031c69a 
0xffffff812c0db410 : 0xffffff800031c9f4 
0xffffff812c0db860 : 0xffffff800030b217 
0xffffff812c0dbf50 : 0xffffff80005cd61b 
0xffffff812c0dbfb0 : 0xffffff80002daa13 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: iTunes

Mac OS version:
11E53

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: A8ED611D-FB0F-3729-8392-E7A32C5E7D74
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 7942805086197
last loaded kext at 7598793861531: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.1.17 (addr 0xffffff7f80791000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 7658871709980: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.1.17 (addr 0xffffff7f80791000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.26
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.1.8
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.42
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.5f11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  225.2
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.5f11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   530.4.20
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.5.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.1.2b2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 193.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   193.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.0f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.0f3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.0f3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc17
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.0.16
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.0d17
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.5f11
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.5f11
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 227.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.5
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.6
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also had problems during startup - no kernel panics, but I was forced to reboot.

```
Process:         configd [562]
Path:            /usr/libexec/configd
Identifier:      configd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-15 23:53:40.734 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  3

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010cf95000-000000010cfbf000 [  168K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/libexec/configd

Application Specific Information:
objc[562]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0:: SCDynamicStore  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7c67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7bd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9394150c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93949c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93949486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   configd                         0x000000010cf96e20 0x10cf95000 + 7712
6   configd                         0x000000010cf9651b 0x10cf95000 + 5403
7   configd                         0x000000010cf95d64 0x10cf95000 + 3428

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7de06 __select_nocancel + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8dc5a4ea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 251
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8dc5931a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7e192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabc594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.Apple80211    0x000000010d32d027 Apple80211Set + 2183
1   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.Apple80211    0x000000010d30b1c7 ioDriverInit + 1729
2   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.Apple80211    0x000000010d30d7fa start + 276
3   configd                         0x000000010cf97ee7 0x10cf95000 + 12007
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93942cb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
5   configd                         0x000000010cf9778e 0x10cf95000 + 10126
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8daba8bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7e192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabc594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7e192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabc594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: InterfaceNamer thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7c67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7bd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9394150c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93949c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93949486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9395919f CFRunLoopRun + 95
6   configd                         0x000000010cfa2165 0x10cf95000 + 53605
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8daba8bf _pthread_start + 335
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7ddf2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93992c8b __CFSocketManager + 1355
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8daba8bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7c67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ec7bd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9394150c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93949c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93949486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9395919f CFRunLoopRun + 95
6   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PPPController 0x000000010d4fa142 pppcntl_run_thread + 2194
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8daba8bf _pthread_start + 335
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dabdb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000010d302950  rbx: 0x00007fda29d07df0  rcx: 0x00007fda29d07e00  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00200000ffffff00  rsi: 0x000000000000002b  rbp: 0x000000010d303480  rsp: 0x000000010d303368
   r8: 0x00007fff7cc04d38   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000000010d303230  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fda2a803788  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fda29d096e0  r15: 0x0000000000000001
  rip: 0x000000010d32d027  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000010d32d000
Logical CPU: 2
```

This last was just 20 minutes ago. After the reboot, everything works well.

This has begun to happen after the latest OS update was installed. I've run memtest, checked the disk, and repaired permissions. The hard drive appears to be fine. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: another panic 2 minutes ago..BSD process name corresponding to current thread: repair_packages

Comment: Running repair permissions won't help in this sort of case, especially if you've not installed any software since you last ran it.

Comment: Repetitive kernel panics even after reinstalls (which rule out a software problem)... this points a lot towards a hardware problem.

Answer (score 3):

Can you take the machine into your local Apple Store or Apple Authorized reseller? Kernel panics that continue over OS reinstalls are indicative of hardware problems, possibly the logic board.

Comment: logic board????whats that?i went to the genius bar one month ago they did the hardware check and it seemed all right

Comment: It's the mainboard where the CPU and GPU sit and the RAM plugs into.

Comment: it could be also..

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to the debug output.  You're getting general protection faults (in the kernel panic message) and segmentation faults (in the configd crash message)--these are signs of memory trouble.  Try running a memory test such as [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

**Edit:** You stated that the system is running on third-party memory modules.  You still have the OEM modules; installing laptop memory is a fairly simple job.  Try looking at [this page](http://www.crucial.com/install/sodimm.aspx) for information on how to do it.

Comment: brillant im checkin it..just time to do it

Comment: it doesn't appears as a compatible mac software

Comment: Try using the memory test on the Mac Hardware Test CD or DVD.

Comment: i know but apple doesn't put the cd in the new boxes with lion..also to reinstall the os i made it with the internet connection from the apple store

Comment: It should be on the install DVD.  If you don't have it, I guess you'll have to try bringing it to the Genius Bar once again...

Comment: its a third part ddr memory when i went to the genius we did the hardware check and it wasn't able to recognise the ram because it s not original!somebody in italy (an authorised seller) did this mistake...i will solve the problem in august when i`ll return there...so is it the memory?is it dangerous wait till august? :(

Comment: I don't think this is dangerous, and I suppose you either have your data backed up or have no important data on the system, but your computer will remain unusable until you get back to Italy.  You might want to try replacing the memory modules, but be careful if you do this.

Comment: i paid to have the original parts,and he will put those!anyway yes i`ve already done the backup with time machine in an external drive in the beginning of may and right now the system is simple and without an excessive quantity of apps,i thought it was the best solution to control it as well!now i`m sure about the causes thanks to you and thanks to this useful site!regards

Comment: If this is the best answer, click on the check mark below the up/down voting controls to accept it.  This signals that this question has been resolved.  *Moderators: I'm not moving this discussion to chat because the question author does not have enough reputation to talk in chat.*

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is panicking when AppleHWSensor is loaded, if it's not a software problem, it's because your logic board is overheating. In that case this is expected behavior.